# TypeScript, react testing missing type in AnyAction

Tags: typescript, redux-thunk, react-testing-library

I'm having this error:

```
TS2345: Argument of type '(dispatch: Dispatch) => Promise<void>' is not assignable to parameter of
type 'AnyAction'.   Property 'type' is missing in type '(dispatch: Dispatch) => Promise<void>' but
required in type 'AnyAction'. type' is declared here* :
```

`*` The code of the declaration is:

```
export interface Action<T = any> {
  type: T
}
```

AnyAction extends Action.

This is my code on the test:

```
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import reduxThunk from 'redux-thunk';
// some code, then in the test I have:

const mockStore = configureStore([reduxThunk]);
const store = mockStore({});

store.dispatch(signIn()); //here I have the error
```

The definition of `signIn` is:

```
export const signIn = () =>
  async (dispatch: Dispatch): Promise<void> => {
    dispatch({
      type: SIGN_IN_REQUEST
    });
  };
```

Any hint or idea on how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`configureStore` allows us to pass arguments to express dispatch extensions so in order to make it work with `redux-thunk` we have to specify `ThunkDispatch` as argument as following:

```js
import { ThunkDispatch } from 'redux-thunk';

// your app state
interface AppState {}

// you can even express more params for `ThunkDispatch`
const mockStore = configureMockStore<AppState, ThunkDispatch<AppState, any, any>>([])
```

Answer (score 0):

As tmho2005 said, I did that by reading his answer and another similar thread. This is my code in case anyone wants it:

```
// only relevant code for the question
import { AnyAction } from 'redux';
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import reduxThunk, { ThunkDispatch } from 'redux-thunk';

import { AuthState } from '../../../types'; // that's the definition of my app state

type DispatchExts = ThunkDispatch<AuthState, void, AnyAction>;

// And the code for mys tests:

const mockStore = configureStore<AuthState, DispatchExts>([reduxThunk]);
const store = mockStore(defaultState);

await store.dispatch(signIn({
  username: 'foo',
  password: 'bar'
}));
```